# flutter google login not working with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

greeting to all,
I am trying to do google login in flutter using firebase but somehow It is not working. it does not show the authenticated user on the firebase console also.

below is the code for the login -:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pages/Rounded_Button.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'Page1.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';



class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------google sign in method

  bool _isLoggedIn = false;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);


  _login() async{
    try{
      await _googleSignIn.signIn().then((value){
        setState(() {
          _isLoggedIn = true;
        });

        userInformation(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page1()
        ));

      });

      print(_googleSignIn.currentUser.email);
      print(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id);
      print(_googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName);
      print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }


  //==========================================================================================user information

  void userInformation(var id){
    firestore.collection("UserProfile").doc(id).set(
        {
          "uid" : "$id",
          "username" : "",
          "userage" : "",
          "useraltemail" : "",
          "usergender" : "",
        }).then((_){
      print("success!");
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 30.0, left: 30, bottom: 20),
              child: RoundedButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google, color: Colors.deepOrange,),
                name: 'Continue With Google',
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                onpresses: (){
                  _login();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below are the dependencies -:

```
  cloud_firestore: any
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.0
```

below is the error I am getting while login -:

```
I/flutter (21435): shrey@gmail.com
I/flutter (21435): xxxx3340865662223xxxx
I/flutter (21435): Shrey Pandey
I/flutter (21435): null
E/flutter (21435): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does
not have permission to execute the specified operation.
E/flutter (21435): #0      MethodChannelDocumentReference.set (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_chann
el_document_reference.dart:43)
E/flutter (21435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21435): #1      _WelcomePageState.userInformation.<anonymous closure> (package:pages/HomePage.dart:85)
E/flutter (21435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21435):
```

can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: maybe you have rule setted which preventing the entry, try checking it. 
Firestore > Rules section

Answer (score 0):

> E/flutter (21435): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does
> not have permission to execute the specified operation.

**PERMISSION_DENIED**

> The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

check if your firestore rules allow read and write

Please check that you have registered your app for firebase, and setup SHA256 for [google signup](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/)